# confusion about function call stack

Tags: c, callstack

According to Wiki:

> the caller pushes the return address onto the stack, and the called
>   subroutine, when it finishes, pops the return address off the call
>   stack and transfers control to that address.

**Pic from Wiki:**

[image]

I don't quite understand this.
Say I have a C program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int x)
{
    return x+1;
}

void spam()
{
    int a = 1;  //local variable
    int b = foo(a);  //subroutine called
    int c = b;  //local variable
}

int main()
{
    spam();
    return 0;
}
```

And I think the call stack should be something like a drawing as follows:

```
<None> means none local variables or params

      _| parameters for foo() <int x>  |_
top    | local of spam() <int c>       |
^      | return address of foo()       |<---foo() called, when finishes, return here?
|      | local of spam() <int b>       |
bot    | local of spam() <int a>       |
      _| parameters for spam() <None>  |_
       | locals of main() <None>       | 
       | return address of spam()      |<---spam() called, when finishes, return here?
       | parameters for main() <None>  |
```

Question:

According to the words quoted from Wiki,

> the called subroutine, when it finishes, pops the return address off
>   the call stack and transfers control to that address.

1.Is my drawing right?

2.If it is right, then when foo() finishes, it will

> pop the return address off the call   stack and transfer control to
>   that address

, but how can it pop off the return address?
  Because when foo finishes, the current stack pointer is pointing to spam's local ,
  right?

**UPDATE:**

what if the main() looks like this:

```
int main()
{ 
    spam();
    foo();
}
```

then what the call stack should look like?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your drawing is not correct. The local stack variables for a function are all below any return addresses. Otherwise, as you have observed, the locals would get lost when you call a function.

It should be like this:

```
| parameters for foo() <int x>  |
| return address of foo()       |
| local of spam() <int c>       |
| local of spam() <int b>       |
| local of spam() <int a>       |
| parameters for spam() <None>  |
| return address of spam()      |
| locals of main() <None>       | 
| parameters for main() <None>  |
```

I think the confusion is that you believe that variable declarations are treated as statements and executed in order. In fact the compiler will typically analyse a function to decide how much stack space is needed for all the local variables. Then it emits code to adjust the stack pointer accordingly and that adjustment is made on entry to the function. Any calls to other functions can then push onto the stack without interfering with this function's stack frame.

Comment: yes, sir, I agree with you. But in "spam()", "foo()" is called before "<int c = b>", right? Then where should I put "int c" in the call stack? Also below the return address?

Comment: The stack reservation of the local variables is typically made once and for all at the start of the execution of the function. So a, b and c are all reserved stack space before foo is called.

Comment: Got it, sir. What if I call spam() and foo() in main (see UPDATE)? What will the call stack look like? Do you mean the size of a function's stack frame is the sum of its locals' size?

Comment: David is right in that it seems you're misunderstanding variable declarations as statements executed in order.  Any one function call will only push one stack frame on the call stack.  This stack frame will already have all of the space needed for the function (as defined by the compiler).  Each stack frame will have a return address for when the function returns, and a set amount of space for all parameters and local variables.

Comment: I think I've answered this already. I don't want to get into a long drawn out serious of edits to the question to ask follow-ups. However, in your update, you call spam by pushing the return value, calling the function, poping the return value and jumping there. Then you call foo in exactly the same way. Finally, your updated question isn't fully specified because the call stack will look different at different stages of execution.